# error after installing bootstrap in an existing vue project

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have an existing Vue project and I want to add Boostrap into it. I ran this command (following [this tutorial](https://travishorn.com/adding-bootstrap-to-a-vue-cli-project-98c2a30e0ed0))

```
npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

And then, I got an error in the Vue project.

```
./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js module build failed: error: enoent: no such file or directory
```

I have tried deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` then running `npm install`, but it didn't work. I also have tried to clear cache but it didn't work. I also have tried running `npm install` from my cmd but it didn't work as well.

Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of vue are you using (2, 3)? Have you considered using [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#using-module-bundlers)?

Comment: I'm using Vue 2. I have tried Bootstrap Vue but it gave me the same error message.

Comment: Is your project public? Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same method a few hours later and it succeeded. I think probably it also depends on your Internet connection.